# How to get second line of JSON object with no key

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON payload coming from API:

```
{   "soap:Envelope": {     "xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",     "xmlns:soap": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",     "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",     "soap:Body": {       "PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE": {         "xmlns": "http://xx.xx.x.x:xxxx/",         "PERAQCONSULTARESULT": {           "STRING": [             "S",             "01;01;310990;20220311;20230310;30;0;0;0;20231016;14;5;1;0;20231225;5;0;        ;0;0;                                        ;",             "01;01;310990;20230311;20240310;0;7.5;0;0;        ;0;0; ;0;        ;0;0;        ;0;0;                                        ;"           ]         }       }     }   } }
```

I was able to access the result with the following:

```
var itens = jsonObject["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE"]["PERAQCONSULTARESULT"]["STRING"]

itens =  [   "S",   "01;01;310990;20220311;20230310;30;0;0;0;20231016;14;5;1;0;20231225;5;0;        ;0;0;                                   ;",   "01;01;310990;20230311;20240310;0;7.5;0;0;        ;0;0; ;0;        ;0;0;        ;0;0;                                        ;" ]
```

I wonder how can I access separately each one of the lines on this itens variable

Thanks,
Vini

I tried accessing like this:

```
var itens = jsonObject["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE"]["PERAQCONSULTARESULT"]["STRING[0]"]
```

but was unable to get it

I am expecting to get each line separately like

```
"01;01;310990;20220311;20230310;30;0;0;0;20231016;14;5;1;0;20231225;5;0;        ;0;0;                                        ;",
```

Comment: "second line of JSON object"? What does "line" mean?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonObject["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE"]["PERAQCONSULTARESULT"]["STRING"]` is an array so use array item access by index:

```
var itens = jsonObject["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE"]["PERAQCONSULTARESULT"]["STRING"][0];
```

Or destructuring assignment/declaration:

```
var [itens] = jsonObject["soap:Envelope"]["soap:Body"]["PERAQCONSULTARESPONSE"]["PERAQCONSULTARESULT"]["STRING"];
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#declaration_with_destructuring